# How to add an empty data point to a linechart on Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to add empty data points throughout a line chart using Chart.js. I have this:

```
var data = {
            labels: [
                "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Traffic",
                    data: null,null,20,40,null,null,null,10,20,null
                }
            ]
        };
```

The problem is that the linechart only recognizes the first two "nulls" as being empty data points and doesn't display them. However, for the nulls that come after, a line (connecting the previous and next valid datapoint) is shown, which makes it seem as if the "null"-datapoints actually exist. Is there a way to NOT display null-values in linecharts? (Similar to what Canvas.js offer: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/empty-null-data-points-chart/)

I read through the Chart.js documentation and stackoverflow but could not find an answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Because 0 infers a valid data point, which means 0. Null would infer no data point at all.

Comment: There is a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462042/line-chartjs-empty-null-values-doesnt-break-the-line/30478786#30478786

Answer (score 16):

I read [line documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) and found a boolean option which is called `spanGaps`

Here's a piece of code, which i used to display this:

```
{
    'type': 'line',
    'data': {
        'labels': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],

        'datasets': [{
            'label': 'example',
            'data': [4, 1, null, 3],

            // These are style properties, there is no need to copy them
            'borderColor': 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'borderWidth': 1,
            'fill': false,
            tension: 0.2,
        }]
    },

    'options': {
        spanGaps: true // this is the property I found
     }
}
```

Chart with `spanGaps = false`:

[image: Chart with spanGaps = false]

Chart with `spanGaps = true`
[image: Chart with spangaps = true]

Comment: Thank you, this boolean option worked for me! Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Posting the summary of the answer at [Line ChartJS empty / null values doesn't break the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462042/line-chartjs-empty-null-values-doesnt-break-the-line/30478786#30478786) WITH (slight) corrections for the question above

Extend the line chart

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        // now draw the segments
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx
        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.strokeColor

            var previousPoint = {
                value: null
            };
            dataset.points.forEach(function (point) {
                if (previousPoint.value !== null && point.value !== null) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
                    ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                previousPoint = point;
            })
        })
    }
});
```

You have to call the LineAlt thus

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data, {
    datasetStrokeWidth: 0.01,
    datasetFill: false,
    pointDotRadius : 2,
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 3
});
```

Other changes made for your question - data should be an array and not a comma separated set of values value

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zu3p2nky/

## Edit Aug 2016

This now works out of box without the need for an extension, just be using the `null` as a data point.