# Charts.js fill transparent if no data on some points

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to fill data points and line with transparent color if there is zero or no data on some data points.

[image]

```
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
                pointColor: "#000000",
                pointStrokeColor: "#000000",
                pointHighlightFill: "#000000",
                pointHighlightStroke: "#000000",
                data: [0, 0, 35, 35, 0, 35, 35, 35, 35, 0, 0, 35, 35]
            }
```

In this image points with data and lines between them is showing only when there is data above 0 in data points.
But this is not happening as it fill with 0 data and it drops line and point to 0. Is there any way so I could draft a chart like this image?

Comment: can you not just use `null` instead of `0`

Comment: Thanks @Quince for replying, I tried but it seams that null won't hide lines between two points.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462042/line-chartjs-empty-null-values-doesnt-break-the-line/30478786#30478786

Comment: thanks @potatopeelings I got it, it's working.